# ionic 2 Typescript Error TS1005 after updated to ionic-native 2.5.1

Tags: typescript, ionic2, ionic-native

I'm getting Typescript errors when I run "ionic serve" in my terminal after updated to the latest ionic-native (2.5.1) in my ionic 2 project. I have tried to update typescript to version 2.x but still not work. Please help.

The error messages:

```
TypeScript error: ../ionic2/ionic2-angularfire-sample-master/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/mixpanel.d.ts(74,21): Error TS1005: '=' expected.
TypeScript error: ../ionic2/ionic2-angularfire-sample-master/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/mixpanel.d.ts(74,27): Error TS1005: ';' expected.
TypeScript error: ../ionic2/ionic2-angularfire-sample-master/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/mixpanel.d.ts(74,29): Error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
TypeScript error: ../ionic2/ionic2-angularfire-sample-master/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/mixpanel.d.ts(75,1): Error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

My ionic info:

> ```
> Your system information:
> Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
> Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1
> ```

My package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.53",
    "angular": "^1.6.2",
    "angularfire2": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
    "firebase": "3.3.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ionic-native": "^2.5.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "2.13.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "^1.1.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-tslint": "^1.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5",
    "tslint": "^3.10.1",
    "tslint-ionic-rules": "^0.0.3",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^2.1.0"
```

My typescript version in tsc -v:

```
Version 2.2.1
```

Please help. Thank you!!!

Comment: update your post with this **mixpanel.ts** file

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of issues here.

Your **Ionic Framework is in Beta**.

You should do `npm install -g ionic@latest`.

To get the latest dependencies for Ionic project you can refer the package.json for the starter base [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/blob/master/ionic-angular/base/package.json). These are the dependencies downloaded when you do `ionic start proj --v2 template_name`.

Note: 
Even this package.json specifies ionic-native version `2.4.1` and app scripts as `1.1.3` while yours is mentioned higher.

Comment: Thanks for reply. After I did `npm install -g ionic@latest`, it made another problem that `Error: Cannot find module '@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc'`. Please help. @suraj

Comment: Did you check the package.json?

Comment: Do you mean I need to put the new package.json created from a new project to my current project?

Comment: You could do that and add all the additional  dependencies  you seem to have and check